# how do I return a previously calculated result in clojure?

Tags: clojure

I am new to clojure, so excuse me, if I am not using the right terminology yet. I am looking for a way, to do the following in the most idiomatic way:

I have a function that merges any given number of maps into one, let's call it `merge-maps`.

Now I need a second function that calls the first, then calls a static void java function with the result and then returns the exact same result. I get the first two things, but I fail in doing the third. Since the static void method evaulates to nil, I have to somehow return the value, but I don't understand how:

```
(defn my-funky-function [& ms]
   (def merged (merge-maps ms))
   (SomeJavaClass/someStaticVoidMethod merged, "some", "other", "stuff")
   ;????? <- how do I "return" merged from here?)
)
```

Comment: IIRC result of evaluation of last line in a function is the return value.

Comment: You shall **never** use `def` inside of a function. Not only because you're affecting global scope, but also because Clojure creates vars for `def` during the compilation

Comment: @m0skit0 It is not, because void methods return nil.

Comment: Sure, I mean for non-void functions (not methods, this ain't OOP).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for a function, and also don't use `def` inside of a function unless you explicitly intend to "create and intern a global var" (docstring of `def`). Merging maps can be done with `merge`.

```
(doto (merge ms) (SomeJavaClass/someStaticVoidMethod "some" "other" "stuff"))
```

**EDIT**: Because my answer may be misunderstood regarding the correct use of def (see Leonids comment): Using def inside of a function is never a good idea. I quoted from the docstring to hint at the global effect of using def which you certainly don't want to have in your function.

**EDIT2:** Here a bit of more explanation regarding the line above: doto always returns it's first argument. If it is mutable and the expressions after it modify it as a side effect, the modified version is returned. However, if you just want to invoke a static method that (presumably) has side effects that don't modify the first argument, it is correct to use doto because you can rely on the immutability of your maps.

Since you were asking for a general idiomatic approach and want to solve a similar problem when your static method (or function with side effects) does not expect your desired return value as a first argument, you can always do this:

```
(doto (merge ms) (#(SomeJavaClass/someStaticMethod "Some" "other" "stuff" %)))
```

Now if for any reason you need to be sure that the static method never modifies the argument (if it is a mutable thing), using a let block doesn't help. This is because in the let-block you are binding a symbol to the mutable thing and you would not get it's old value from the symbol. You would need to create a copy of the old value beforehand, usually by invoking it's constructor and creating a new instance of it.

Example at the repl:

```
(let [a (into-array [4 3 2 1]]
  (java.util.Arrays/sort a)
  a)
(first *1)
=> 1

;; now how to return the original thiing
(let [a (into-array [4 3 2 1])
      a-copy (aclone a)]
  (java.util.Arrays/sort a)
  ;; do some other ops on a, maybe invoke side-effects
  a-copy)
(first *1)
=> 4
```

So if the first let-block produces your desired result, the let-block can be replaced with doto which is a helper macro that does exactly nothing else than creating that let-block for you.

```
(doto (into-array [4 3 2 1]) java.util.Arrays/sort)
(first *1)
=> 1
(macroexpand '(doto (into-array [4 3 2 1]) java.util.Arrays/sort))
=> (let* [G__7326 (into-array [4 3 2 1])] (java.util.Arrays/sort G__7326) G__7326)
```

Since you are not "doing anything" to your merged-maps, the name "doto" might be slightly misleading but hopefully I could convice you to save a few lines of redundant code.

Comment: It's a really bad idea to use `def` for global vars. There are lots of other ways to do so: atoms, dynamic vars (see [set!](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/set!)), refs. `def` meant to be used only once per variable (to set root binding) and only from the top level.

Comment: I totally agree with you. Did you want to write that comment on Dominics answer? I can hardly imagine a reason to use def inside of a function. Maybe to reset a kitchensink like namespace that is only used from the repl for development. But I never did that and would certainly not recommend it. I quoted from the docstring to hint at the effects of def, also to make clear that binding symbols with def is not the same as using let-bindings.

Answer (score 1):

Like this

```
(defn my-funky-function [& ms]
   (def merged (merge-maps ms))
   (SomeJavaClass/someStaticVoidMethod merged, "some", "other", "stuff")
   merged)
```

Note: you should use a `let` binding instead of creating a Var with `def`.

```
(defn my-funky-function [& ms]
   (let [merged (merge-maps ms)]
     (SomeJavaClass/someStaticVoidMethod merged, "some", "other", "stuff")
     merged))
```

Comment: the first option is not thread safe. If two call to my-funky-function happen at the same time they will share a single value of merged. there is almost never a reason to use def in a function. Would you mind removing that example so people don't copy it?

Comment: @ArthurUlfeldt I replaced *you could use let instead of def* with *you should use let instead of def*